# Magento1.6 Custom Status in Admin

Tags: magento

I want add all status in magento sales order Comment History Box. I have magento1.6.2.0.
I have try to changing in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml file and add statuses but nothing was changed please help.

Answer (score 1):

No need to change in the code go to *Admin Panel->System->Order Statuses* you could create states and assign them to whichever status you want them to be.

In magento *States* are the visible status of the order and *Status* is the internal status of the order. A bit confusing but if you take a look at the page you should be to get an idea of what this means.

Comment: I got solution and it what i actually want. check below for solution.
http://www.ram-magento.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-change-order-status-in-magento16.html

Comment: @RamRam comment above was THE solution I was looking for.